# How to properly insert a Bootstrap navbar in a Codeigniter view?

Tags: codeigniter, view, twitter-bootstrap-3, frameworks

I'm learning to develop with CodeIgniter and would like a help to know how to properly insert a navbar in a view. I need to know which directory to save the navbar file and how to call this file in a view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $produto['nome']; ?></title>
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>">
</head>
<body>
    I need navbar here (This is a home view)
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php echo $produto['nome']; ?>
                <?php echo $produto['preco']; ?>
                <?php echo $produto['descricao']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is defined method to access it. you can use place and use it where ever you want(inside view folder)

Comment: Just follow this tutorial: https://blog.eduonix.com/web-programming-tutorials/learn-integrate-bootstrap-4-codeigniter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try create a template folder inside views folder and put some files like header.php, nav.php, footer.php. Inside your main view you can use like `$this->load->view('template/nav);`.

**UPDATED**

This is the typical of **header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   ...
   <title>Put_your_title_here</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>">
   ...
  </head>
  <body>
   <!-- depends on your template design -->
   <div class="dashboard-wrapper">
    <div class="main-content">
     <?php $this->load->view('template/nav.php'); ?>
```

**footer.php**

```
    <footer>Some footer content</footer>
   </div><!-- /.main-content -->
  </div><!-- /.dashboard-wrapper -->

  <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**nav.php**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
...
</div>
```

Let say that your Controller (in this case **Welcome.php**) load a view like this:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function home()
  {
    $data['message'] = 'Welcome to My Website';
    $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
  }
}
```

**welcome.php**

```
<?php $this->load->view('template/header'); ?>

  <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>

<?php $this->load->view('template/header'); ?>
```

> **NOTE** Avoid echoing something directly from controller except some particular situation that force you to do so